# socket.emit not working client side or server side not getting

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

So I am coding an online idle game using socket.io and node.js(first time) that saves your progress via a login and arrays on the server side. And when I have the client socket.emit the credentials the user entered it should be sent to the server. My function in the client side is completing(I have a console.log at the end) but i'm not sure if the server isn't receiving it or if the client isn't sending it. I couldn't find any articles with fixes that worked for me. I don't get any errors when I run it. here are some snippets of my code:

```
//client
var username = 'example'
var password = 'example'
socket.emit('login', username, password);
console.log('data succesfully sent')
```

server:

```
var io = require('socket.io')(http);


io.on('connection', function(socket) {
console.log('new user connected')
io.sockets.emit('welcome', 'Someone new connected')



  io.on('login', function(username, password) {
  console.log('login attempted')
//...
  )}
```

Comment: "server", `socket.on('login' ...` instead of `io.on('login'...`

Comment: hoangdv Thank You So much, that worked